# Converting map data to image tiles

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

I’m trying to find a good solution to convert map data into image tiles that I can display on a website using cesium.

I do have a working version of gdal2tile.py script and I can do the conversion, but some data takes a long time (over 2 hours for some data over Hawaii).

I was looking for a way to improve this performance.

Here are the steps I'm doing.

1. I use gdalbuildvrt.exe to generate the vrt file from all the map images I have in a folder.
2. Once that is done I use the gdal2tile.py command to convert the data into map tiles. Here is the command I'm using

`python gdal2tile.py -z 0-12 test.vrt testtile`

Depending on the size of the map files it can take up to 2 hours to finish.

Is there a way to figure out the available zoom levels based on the resolution? I noticed that some zoom levels are only 1 or 2 images and blurry.

Is this the correct way to do it? Generate the VRT file and use that to generate the tiles?

Also sometimes when I call the `gdal2tile.py` it asks me to do a conversion. Here is an example error.

```
gdal2tiles.py: error: Please convert this file to RGB/RGBA and run gdal2tiles on the result.


From paletted file you can create RGBA file (temp.vrt) by:
gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba visnav.vrt temp.vrt
then run:
gdal2tiles temp.vrt
```

Comment: Hi, what exactly is your question? Performance? If so, you got to specify exactly what your input and environment is. Or are you looking for alternative software?

Comment: Sorry, so I was looking for both better performance and also an alternative so I can compare the differences

Comment: Others could better consider if your speed is normal or not if you add how many tiles per second or minute gdal2tiles creates for you. Show also your gdal2tiles command. Number of tiles increases fast with the zoom level https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels. z8 has 42 tiles per square kilometer, z9 170, and z20 680 tiles per km2.

Comment: I will post the command here soon, is there an easy way to get the stats from the command line?